# Build faild in 32s Gradle task assembleDebug failedwith exit code 1

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, google-signin

can u guys help me pls

what went wrong ;
execution failed for task ':app::compileFlutterDesbug'

while

process comand c:\user\flutter.bat finished with non zero exit values 1

Comment: please provide more details

Comment: Can I see your result of ```flutter doctor -v

Answer (score 0):

follow this steps:

1: open your terminal and run this code => `flutter clean`.

2: delete pubspec.lock file .

2.5: delete gradle directory.

3: `File=>open=>`   open your android directory on your project in new windows.

4: let android gradle downloaded .

5: restart and clear android studio catch and try build it.